# Samsung Galaxy tab E new SD card shows no free space

Tags: external-sd

Good day,

Trying to save some films onto a brand new SD card on my wifes Samsung Galaxy tab E. She has downloaded Showbox and when we hit the download button the screen shows 'no available space on SD'. It's a 32GB Sandisk by the way. The system recognises it, and I have moved a couple of apps over to test it and they transfer ok. I formatted the card before I started and it is getting a bit frustrating now. Anything I am not doing ?

Bill

Comment: Sd card could many times mean the local storage. Make sure to select in the app that you want it to go to extremal memory.

Comment: There is an 8GB memory on the device of which 4.3 is taken with mostly Google stuff we don't need that can't be moved to the external disk. I have just been through all the programmes cleared all the data, and moved what I could to the external SD so we are left with things we don't need and unable to move them taking up an awful amount of space. I was wondering whether a reset to as new might do the trick. The Showbox app is one that cannot be moved either.

Comment: Factory reset will not clear up too much space, as the phone takes up allot of memory on it's own

Comment: A bit stuck then. It is a micro disk. If I put that in my pc, downloaded whatever films required and then moved that back to the tablet, would that work?

Comment: If you're able to download it as a video file on your computer, you should then be able to move it to your sd card and play it in the regular video player, but probably not the showbox app

Comment: I don't have show box, but are you able to download videos from a browser? Or does it have to be the app?

Comment: Answer to both, we are using the Showbox app only because it has the latest films. I might try and install that on my PC which is where I am writing from. I don't watch them myself but the wife is away on holiday shortly and wanted to take some films with her and I thought downloading them would be easy. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: What Android version is running on the device? It might simply be that the app doesn't get permission to write to "external storage". Go to *Settings* and check whether r/w access to storage has been granted.

Comment: It's an Android 4.4.4 and I don't know how to do the last.